# I want to spawn a series of 20~ objects with of 3 different types spread randomly throughout the series yet it will only spawn 20 of one object type

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a section of code within a game in Unity which is meant to create a series of 20 objects with a 3 in 5 chance of generating a Basic Object (BO), a 1 in 5 chance of generating Special Object 1 (SO1) and another 1 in 5 chance of generating Special Object 2 (SO2). The objects should be generated in a random mix of the 3 types spread throughout the 20 object sequence. However instead of creating a 20 object sequence of a mixture of the objects it creates a 20 object sequence of 1 type of object with the above chances of the sequence being made completely of said objects. Here is my code.

```
 int x = 0;
    do
    {
        var r = new System.Random();
        int objectType = r.Next(1, 6);

        if (objectType < 4)
        {
            SpawnBO();
        }
        else if (objectType == 4)
        {
            SpawnSO1();
        }
        else if (objectType == 5)
        {
            SpawnSO2();
        }

        x++;
    } while (x < 20);
```

I have tried putting the `x++;` within each part of the `if` statement but I still get the same result. Any ideas on how I can get it to create a mixture of the objects instead?

Comment: You didn't check what "random" numbers you were generating.  One hint is to debug when things don't work like you expect.  What do you notice about the random numbers being generated?  Anything stand out?

Comment: [Random number generator only generating one random number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/767999/327083)